# Asking people to read a book

Tags: discussion

In my current [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056420/an-error-with-ets-and-reading-file) the answer (presumably from the author of the book) says that I didn't really understand the chapter of the book describing what I need to do.
I'm currently doing my best re-reading it and trying to figure out a way to do what the answer suggests I should have been doing in the first place.
But I'm not very good at Erlang, currently (although good enough to follow clear instructions in a book).
So, is it OK for me to ask other people to read the necessary chapter and help me understand exactly what I should do?
Also, if people agree to read a chapter, is it OK for them to pass judgement of a kind "there were no clear instructions there, no wonder you didn't get it"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not OK to ask others to read book/chapter/article to "help you understand it".

Such request immediately moves question into "looking for tutorial" and "too broad" (as it rarely clear why you don't get the article and may need article of comparable length to explain) category.

If you can distill problem you have to one concrete question that fits into a page - it is good time to ask it. Otherwise continue researching - there is never too much effort :) - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'll go on researching, then.

Comment: "Explain this whole chapter of a book" isn't a request for a tutorial.  It's unquestionably too broad, but it's not a recommendation request.

Answer (score 10):

Questions on Stack Overflow must stand on their own, so if you could fully explain the problem that you're having with a specific topic in a book in a way that doesn't require someone to have the book available, that would be fine. We often see good questions that present a specific topic or problem from a book, with an explanation and code attempts. If others in the future could benefit from a programming question that you've asked about a book, it's probably a viable question for Stack Overflow.

On a side note, the specific language that answerer used while responding to your question was not acceptable. That's why it was removed by a moderator.

The remainder of the answer did seem to point to a solution, which is why the answer was edited and not outright deleted. Had it been just the rather insulting accusation that you hadn't read the material, we would have removed the entire thing.

Comment: I see, and I agree. The question, though, was not about the answer given but about whether it's all right if I ask others to help me understand a book.

Comment: @Chiffa - Questions on Stack Overflow must stand on their own, so if you could fully explain the problem that you're having with a specific topic in a book in a way that doesn't require someone to have the book available, that would be fine. We often see good questions that present a specific topic or problem from a book, with an explanation and code attempts. If others in the future could benefit from a programming question that you've asked about a book, it's probably a viable question for Stack Overflow.