# Offensive flag disputed after offensiveness being fixed by another user?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, disputed-flags

I was doing a review and flagged [a **specific** short offensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36063205/1) like this:

> I am familiar with that platform, and ...
>
> This is occurring because you're an idiot, didn't read the chapter
>   fully, and didn't ...

Now, my flag was disputed and when I read the current version (2nd) revision by a high-rep user, the post was fixed (for social good) and changed to:

> This is occurring because you didn't ...

But still, the OP was offensive IMO. I was wondering if I was doing the right thing to flag this as offensive, and should got a helpful tag for this instead of a disputed one?

Related, as the comments suggest, in cases like this, is the proper action to edit out the offensive part, or flag it?

--EDIT--

Since there have been many comments on why I didn't edit it as the moderator did.

I think an edit like that significantly changes the OP, which I heard is not advisable. The content I am supposed to remove is **blatant offensive material**, and it's not a causal use of an impolite word or some other language issue one could have done inadvertently out of habits.

To the extreme, one could change a "YES" to a "NO", to make the answer right. And I don't think this is anyone's responsibility.

Anyway, I am glad that this brought the post to the attention of a moderator as the answer suggested. I thought it was someone else who beautified the post, and then I my flag got turned down. Also, I got the answer I am looking for about how to handle similar cases.

Comment: You have the rep to edit out the "offensive" part yourself, don't you?

Comment: This is the liability of asking somebody else to do what you can do.  If you don't like the outcome then don't ask.  Do.

Comment: I think there's a dupe for this but yes, If the post can be salvaged with an edit, edit the offensive part out. You'd use the flag if the only thing in the post is, "You're an idiot". You'd also use the flag if the OP kept editing the offensive part back in.

Comment: This is already answered in the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) under [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: So you prefer punishment..  Well, you don't have enough rep for that yet.  Read it back after the edit, is it *still* the appropriate way?  Wasn't that kind of easy to fix?

Comment: *The user might feel that it's OK at SO or even didn't notice that there is anything wrong with it.* - IIRC, there's a notification if your post is edited, correct? Also, I don't think that removing content signals to someone that something is OK. If you want, you can include a link to the Help Center's "Be Nice" policy in your edit summary so they see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll notice that the "high-rep user" who [edited that out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36063205/revisions) was a moderator. In fact, this same answer [was discussed earlier today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319217/asking-people-to-read-a-book/319218#319218).

Spam / offensive flags on a post basically call for the complete removal of said post. In this case, while that particular language was completely inappropriate, the remainder of the answer was still viable. Therefore, the moderator who responded to your flag cleared (disputed) it, which doesn't penalize you in any way, and edited the answer themselves.

We understand where you were coming from, but the post itself didn't need to be destroyed. In fact, you could have even edited out this section of the answer yourself. Again, you weren't penalized for bringing this to our attention, but we are very careful about validating these flags due to the penalties they can impose on the poster.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I got a disputed flag of this type. As you said, where I came from is obvious. I now see the norm. Also, I was hesitating whether to flag this as a "not an answer", because after removing the non-information part such as the self-intro and the offensive, what's left is almost a comment.  Anyways, I got the answer I look for.